# margin-left and margin-right for Setting Center position

Tags: html, css

I want to set the center the `.user-menu` position, but my code below isn't working. How can I solve this?

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="user-menu">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <div class="bought-tickects centered hover-effect"></div>
            <label>تاریخچه خرید</label>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <div class="profile centered hover-effect"></div>
            <label>حساب کاربری</label>
        </div>
        <div class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container-of-selected">
    </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.menu-items {
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.profile {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('Images/folder-contacts-icon.png');
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bought-tickects {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('Images/tickets-icon.png');
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.user-menu {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: specify your width and set margin:0 auto;(top,bottom is put it if u want) thats it..!

Comment: Can you please share the images you used in the css?

Answer (score 10):

Give the `.user-menu` a width, currently it is a block element so it will fill its container.  This causes the `user-menu` to expand to 100% width across the page, which technically is centered, you just don't notice it.

```
.user-menu {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is worked. :) but i want to set display:inline-block to wrapping content...

Answer (score 5):

make this

http://jsfiddle.net/2VMrf/

CSS

```
.user-menu {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
   width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 .user-menu {  
  margin : 0 auto;
width:50%;
clear:both;   
}
```

refer this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/viveksara/Qj9rk/)**
you need to display one by one

```
 .user-menu {  
      margin : 0 auto;
    width:100px;
    clear:both;   
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this class instead of your .user-menu class

```
.user-menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
}
```

Or just add Width to your .user-menu class. That will do the trick for you.

JSFiddle:
[Working Sample.. Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkeFa/)

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to give the width of a tag

```
.user-menu {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```